# Does apple allow to use own https stack in ios apps?

Tags: iphone, app-transport-security

Is it possible to link e.g. `libcurl` to an *iphone* app in order to have complete control over `https` certificates? Or will they typically flag this during review? Is this also a possible way to bypass application transport security? Are *iphone* apps even allowed to make `tcp` connections to port 443?

We use our own root certificate (expired though) for the `APIs` of our product and don't have a central server. All our clients do the necessary checks to never accept any other certificate than the ones signed by us. We want our *iphone* app to connect directly to our product (deployed at customers) and the product uses our certificates and cannot use `tls 1.2` for the next years. Therefore we also want to bypass the strict requirement of application transport security to use `tls 1.2`.